Tailwind RN (twrnc) not responding
please, my custom styles in tailwind.config file is not working with
<View> <Text style={tw ‘border-2 border-solid b-black bg-primary-default’}> This is the style <Text> </View>
Hence, the only style that is not working is my background primary default as it is set in my tailwind.config.js file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


If twrnc is not picking up styles from your tailwind.config.ts.
create a file at the root of your project. Named anything, I named this file tw.ts add the following content to it.
import { create } from 'twrnc';

// import your custom tailwind config
const tailwindConfig = require('./tailwind.config');

// add the custom config to tw
const tw = create(tailwindConfig);

export default tw;

and use the tw from your custom file in your code. For example
// this is a component
import tw from "address-to-your-tw-file";


You can try a more modern approach to work tailwind with react-native with nativewind. Try this - https://www.nativewind.dev/
